# How to find the frequency of the AC source in RL circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, frequency, inductor, passive-networks

I' m asked to find the **frequency** of my **source** with the given data (**RL-serial circuit**):

$$(R_L=3 \Omega;L=0.04H), R=30\Omega, cos(\phi)=0,819 (ind), X_L>X_C$$

This looks easy but somehow I cannot get the result offered in the **result section**:
[image]

The only thing that I did is this:

- $$R_L=\omega L=2\pi fL \Rightarrow f=\frac{R_L}{2\pi}\frac{1}{L}= 11.93 Hz$$
- $$cos\phi=\frac{R}{Z}\Rightarrow Z=\frac{R}{cos\phi}= 36.63\Omega$$
  I also don't understand how I get different results for impedance (**Z**) when I find it through the usual formula:
  $$Z=\sqrt{R^2 + R_L^2}=30.14\Omega; Z\neq Z ?$$

Why isn't the frequency which I got from the first equation correct? What am I doing wrong?

I also referred here but could't find anything relevant: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/series-resonance.html
Can I at least get a hint? I've been starring at this for 2 hours and can't find out the correct way to solve it.

**Original question:**[image]

**EDIT**
I'm given $$R_L  \quad not\quad X_L  $$

Comment: Something seems to be missing. Where does Xc come from?

Comment: Xc is not given, only Xl, I'll now post the original question it is in croatian but you will see the data...

Comment: What is RL? Is it an extra load resistor? Because given that data RL is not the inductive reactance. Things dont add up.

Comment: Actually it must be the series resistance of the inductor so total resistance of the circuit would be 33ohms plus the XL..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer:
[image]
$$R_f=R_L+R=33\Omega$$
$$\phi=arcos(0.819)=35.01$$
$$tg\phi=\frac{X_L}{R_f}\Rightarrow X_L=tg\phi* R_f=23.11$$
$$X_L=\omega L=2\pi fL \Rightarrow f=\frac{X_L}{2*\pi}\frac{1}{L}=\frac{23.11}{2\pi 0.04}= 91.95 Hz$$

Correct answer is **e)** 92Hz

Comment: What is tg? Because I was going to say $$\phi = arctan(X/R)$$

Comment: Tangent as tg...